# DNS requests do not originate from iPhone during Internet Sharing

Tags: networking, dns, ios, internet-sharing

I'm trying to capture DNS requests from a particular iPhone device. The iPhone is connected to a mac mini by usb, and internet sharing is enabled so that all the iPhone's traffic passes through the mac mini.

I used Wireshark to capture connection requests made across all interfaces on the mac mini. I found the following pattern:

1. Device (192.168.2.8) makes a HTTP connection request for `www.bbc.com`
2. Mac mini (192.0.2.5) makes DNS request for `www.bbc.com`
3. DNS server (8.8.8.8) returns IP
4. Device connects to the returned IP.

```
16865   15.041563   192.168.2.8 192.0.2.5   HTTP 175 CONNECT www.bbc.com:443 HTTP/1.1 
17187   15.044637   192.0.2.5   8.8.8.8     DNS  71  Standard query 0x121a A www.bbc.com
17209   15.100623   8.8.8.8     192.0.2.5   DNS  149 Standard query response 0x121a A www.bbc.com CNAME www.bbc.com.pri.bbc.com CNAME bbc.map.fastly.net A 146.75.44.81
16891   15.118605   192.0.2.5   192.168.2.8 HTTP 105 HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

What confuses me here is:

1. The DNS request should be made by the device, but instead it appears to be made by the mac mini.
2. The DNS request is returned to the mac mini and never passed to the device, yet somehow the device knows which IP to connect to.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be how apple choses to implement their internet sharing. The Mac Mini is responsible for all outward connections (DNS, but also HTTP as you can see). I think this falls under the name 'IP masquerading'.

Comment: Did you disable Wi-Fi and cell data on the iPhone just to be sure? Are you also sure Wireshark is able to see the IP traffic tunneled over USB between the iPhone and the Mac mini?

Comment: It's possible I'm missing packets that are going over USB, and somehow not appearing in bridge100 interface. On Big Sur and later, you have to disable System Integrity Protection in order to capture USB traffic (which I haven't done).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how it's supposed to work for a normal HTTP request.

The client, ie mac mine sends a dns request to 8.8.8.8 and gets a reply with the ip for bbc.

Then it connects to bbc via that ip through the iphone.
The iphone isnt a dns server, it doesnt care at all about dns names at all.

All dns requests originates from the client.

Comment: Shouldn't the DNS request originate from the iPhone, not the mac mini?

Comment: On a layer3 level the iphone is visible as it routes the packet out. but on a protocol level its not involved att all. If you send a HTTP packet the iphone will not alter that packet, it will merely send it to the next hop for that destination ip as per its routing table.

Comment: @SkitOxe I think you think OP is using his iPhone to get his Mac mini online, but it's really the other way around. OP is using his Mac mini to get his iPhone online. The iPhone is the client and the Mac mini is just the NAT gateway router.

Comment: Yes - it is as @Spiff said: the iPhone is the client and the mac mini is acting as a router (via internet sharing)

Comment: Oh ok! then i had it all backwards. Then i agree, that trace is puzzling.